css text ellipsis one by one from right to left, instead of all at the same time
When I shrink the screen all elements become ellipsis. Is there a way to change this behavior? I want them to be ellipsis one by one from right to left. The third item should disappear first, the second - second, and then the first one.
I am open to changing the layout, as long as I can keep them in one row and align them in the middle vertically of the container (whatever they contain, this is why I used flexbox). If possible without JavaScript


.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item,
.inner {
  /*without inner wrapper the text won't break into ellipsis, because of the .container flexbox*/
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"> First item with long text </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"> Second item with even longer text </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="inner"> Third item </div>
  </div>
</div>




Honestly, that's really pushing the limits of CSS to breaking point. JS would be optimal.

I'm pretty sure there is no "shrinking" priority in CSS, Maybe you could fake something with flex-shrink but I'm fairly certain that's not going to do what you want.

@Paulie_D With JS I have to track the element size, work with pixels, do calculations, use ResizeObserver... I want to omit all this

There are some things CSS can't do. That's why JS exists.

Your desired behavior sounds a lot like a single line of text! I don't know what other styles you have in mind for the elements, but maybe this will do the trick for you?


.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffff66;
  height:5em;
}
.container2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item1 {
  background-color:pink;
}
.item2 {
  background-color:lime;
}
.item3 {
  background-color:aqua;
}
.bigthing {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  background: purple;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2">
    <span class="item1"> First item with long text </span>
    <span class="item2">
      <span class="bigthing"></span>
      Second item with even longer text 
    </span>
    <span class="item3"> Third item </span>
  </div>
</div>




I asked when I shrink the screen, not an animation

@OktayYuzcan the animation is a simulation of the screen shrinking to help demonstrate the solution. It's helpful to allow people to understand the problem, and helps to demonstrate solutions. Nobody is saying you asked for an animation.

@GershomMaes but it removed the desired behavior of elements being vertically aligned in middle. That is why I used flexbox.

@OktayYuzcan I'm not sure what vertical alignment you're referring to; in your current code it looks like the elements are vertically at the top of the document. This animation on the width property shouldn't have an effect on vertical alignment.

I'm sorry, but the animation styles was code copied from your own question. You can remove those and see the effect when you shrink the screen.

@BjörnBrändewall I edited to add the animation to make the question clearer

@GershomMaes I thought you made a mistake. The container is aligned top of the document. But Items are aligned vertically middle of the container. That is the reason of the flexbox. I mentioned in the question that they need to be aligned vertically whatever they might contain. If that wasn't the case, I wouldn't even need those items

@OktayYuzcan I updated my answer; removed the animation and added flexbox (and a bigger-than-text box) to show that the ellipses and aligment work nonetheless. But if that's not good enough I think you need to be more specific with what you have in mind with "whatever they might contain". Because if you want an ellipsis effect combined with vertical alignment, I can't really imagine much other than a line of text.
